# jQuery - jqGrid populating method in multiple events

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

This is the code I have to populate the jqGrid:

(Sorry..I couldn't get the script in the message without it looking messed up)

The link to the screenshot image: [Screenshot of code](http://i47.tinypic.com/avklxy.jpg)

The above code works (I edited it a bit so it wasn't too long).  SO when I select a dropdown the grid is populated and displayed.

I have a few questions where I hope someone can help me:

1. The jqGrid is not displayed on the initial load. It only comes up when the dropdown change event occcurs. is there a way to have a blank jqGrid displayed just so there is something there until something is populated?
2. I want to move the jQuery code where it calls the web service to populate the jqGrid into its own method.  i want to have multiple ways to populate the grid so I figure if I put that jqGrid code into its own method I can just call that method each time.  So far i'm having trouble getting that to work. 
   Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: You can post your script in the text field, then select it and hit the `{}` button. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Sorry climbage. This is my first time working with jQuery so i'm still very new at this.  I am not too sure where in the link you've provided I should be looking at. 
THanks for providing feedback for me.

Comment: In the future, please just post all of the code in the question. You can read the markdown help to learn how to format the code properly. In the meantime someone will probably be kind enough to fix it for you... if you paste the text itself, and not an image :)

Answer (score 0):

The jqGrid only comes up when the change event occurs, so when the page is loaded you need to manually trigger the change event. For example:

```
$("#ddlContactFilterStatus").change();
```

Moving the `ajax` code into its own function is a good idea. You could start by just defining a `function` containing the code. If you want something more specific, you could show us what you have so far.